# SLComposeViewController not present when not login with facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I am using Login with facebook functionality and get Email Address from facebook. Here is my code.

```
 if (! _accountStore) {
        _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    }

    if (! _facebookAccountType) {
        _facebookAccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    }

    NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey:@"1501842240102594" };

    [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType: _facebookAccountType
                                       options: options
                                    completion: ^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:_facebookAccountType];
        _facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

        SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                            URL:url parameters:nil];
        request.account = _facebookAccount;
        [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dictionaryForFacebookData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                            error:nil];

    //Here dictionaryForFacebookData is dictionary of facebook data.

    }
    else
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Great fun to learn iOS programming at appcoda.com!"];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

        if ([tweetSheet respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)])
        {
            // iOS 8+
            UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [tweetSheet popoverPresentationController];

            presentationController.sourceView = sender; // if button or change to self.view.
        }
    }
    }];
}
```

Here in SLComposeViewController(else part), it shows some error that is **"LaunchServices: invalidationHandler called"**. Before iOS 8 it present SLComposeViewController to shows user to Login Facebook in setting part.

Please help for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
With this you can get user details from facebook
in .m file 

- (void) getuserdetails
{

    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= nil;
    //[self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    if (! FBaccountType) {
        FBaccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    }
    NSString *key =kFBAppId;
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
             self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
             NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);
             [self get];
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"fb error %@",e.description);

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {
                                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                                NSLog(@"%@",e.description);
                                if([e code]== ACErrorAccountNotFound)
                                {
                                    UIAlertView* alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account not found"
                                                                                  message:msgSetUpFBAccount delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
                                    [alt show];
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    UIAlertView* alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msgFBAccessDenied
                                                                                  message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
                                    [alt show];
                                }

                            });
             NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

         }
     }];
}

-(void)get
{

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:requestURL
                                               parameters:nil];
    request.account = self.facebookAccount;
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                         NSError *error)
     {

         if(!error)
         {
             list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

             NSLog(@"Dictionary contains: %@", list );


             if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
             {
                 [self attemptRenewCredentials];
             }
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
             });

         }
         else
         {
             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideLoader) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
             NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
         }

     }];


}



-(void)attemptRenewCredentials{
    [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)self.facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            switch (renewResult) {
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:
                    NSLog(@"Good to go");

                    [self get];
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                {
                    NSLog(@"User declined permission");
                    UIAlertView* alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access Denied"
                                                                  message:@"You declined permission" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
                    [alt show];
                    break;
                }
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                {
                    NSLog(@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry");
                    UIAlertView* alt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access Denied"
                                                                  message:@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
                    [alt show];
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from renew credentials%@",error);
        }
    }];


}
```